# How to create and save documents and templates in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, document

### My Past Experience

I have an experience of around 04 yrs into C# win-forms and a little bit into WPF and a few other languages but am new to ASP.Net (or any web applications).

### Problem Description

I want to create a documents management site internal to my company where an admin can define the templates (like in visual studio we get project templates so we can get whether to create a text or spread sheet or other types of document like MS Word or Excel) and multiple fields can be added to it and saved. Then the users can access the saved templates and create their own files (with same template but different data) and save it. I need to save the version changes also.

### How do I approach it ?

1. Is it very difficult to achieve rich document support in ASP.Net (like in WPF) ?
2. Is it re-inventing the wheel (because there is google docs or people can buy MS Office and create documents and save it in server) though not all would buy it ?
3. Should I save the templates as Xml or  HTML in the DB or how ?

Any starting point or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Is basing your project on SharePoint a viable option?

Comment: @YannickBlondeau : Probably not - because my company might not invest in SharePoint and the learning curve involved. I have read some where that share point saves the documents in MS SQL as blobs. I want my approach to incur minimum investments and quickest way.

Comment: Sharepoint is definitely a viable starting point for reference/benchmark. You can use the less costly alternatives using a LAMP stack and mimic the features of Sharepoint if you can code it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is not that difficult to do. I just finished up a project where the entire UI revolved around allowing the user to create, save, edit, and then fill in templates. You can actually save the information in a byte array and then save that to the database. Here is an example of a new template method I used. Its not difficult but way more information that can be included here. The creation of the form is the hardest part. The form creation for this one is 3100 lines of code.

```
private void doNew()
    {
        try
        {
            this.m_bDialogOpen = true;
            //New instance of data object
            MergeLetterDocsDO clnt = new MergeLetterDocsDO(7);
            //Creates a new title or name for the template
            NewMergeLetterTitle title = new NewMergeLetterTitle("New Merge Letter", 7);
            DialogResult dr = title.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                Form1 frm = new Form1(Simple.Form1.DocumentTypes.MERGE_LETTER,  Simple.Form1.OperationModes.DESIGN_TIME, null);
                frm.ShowDialog(this);

                byte[] bb = frm.InternalFormatDocument;
                byte[] rtfbb = frm.RtfFormatDocument;
                clnt.SaveNewMergeTemplate(bb, rtfbb, bb.Length, rtfbb.Length, title.MergeLetterTitle);
            }

            this.m_bDialogOpen = false;

            this.Populate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }O
```